# Where to keep the contents when creating a bat file

Tags: c#, desktop-application

I trying to create a bat file using csharp which contains some commands.

So which is the best place to keep this commands so that I can fetch it while creating the batch file? It is ok to keep it inside a string variable? See below the sample commands that I need to keep inside the bat file.

```
 @echo off
  set seconds=45
  echo Waiting to start...
```

....etc

**Edit:** The contents of the bat file are static one, it never changes.

Any help much appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how dynamic your batch file contents will be, it would be fine to use strings to store the contents. I recommend using the `StringBuilder` class to build out your batch file.

If your batch file contents are static, it might be better to store the file as a resource in your application.

Comment: My content is a static one, it will never change.. Is it ok to store in a text file inside the project?

Comment: @Bhaskar If the content is static, why don't you just create the batch file? Why bother building it with C# to begin with?

Comment: @BhaskarK: Or just perform the operations directly in C#, whichever you are more comfortable in.

Comment: I am developing an desktop application and I need to create a bat file when the application starts. 

@Thomas are you advising me to keep the bat file as an resource file in the project?

Comment: @Lamps If it never changes, absolutely. Why waste time building something that's identical every time you build it?